# JAXB2 Basics Plugins - Issue with schemaLocation in my External binding customization file

Tags: maven, xsd, jaxb, xjc, jaxb2-basics

I am using JAXB to generate classes from my XSD file. I would like to have the classes that are generated implement a common interface. So I am trying out the JAXB2 Basics plugin with the [external binding file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148366) approach to do this. This is my custom binding file:

**customBindingFile.xjb**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" 
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
  jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="abc-api.xsd">
      <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='MyClass']">
        <inheritance:implements>com.kuldeep.CommonInterface</inheritance:implements> 
      </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Following is my maven plugin in pom file for source generation:
Note the comment **added by me** is the change I made to this existing plugin entry.

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${cxf.plugin.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-sources</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>

      <!-- **extensions and args added by me** -->
        <extensions>
            <extension>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:0.9.2</extension>
        </extensions>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
        </args>


        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
        <defaultOptions>
          <bindingFiles>
            <bindingFile>src/main/resources/jaxws_binding.xml</bindingFile>
            <bindingFile>src/main/resources/jaxb_binding.xml</bindingFile>
          </bindingFiles>
        </defaultOptions>
        <wsdlOptions>
          ......
          <wsdlOption>
            <wsdl>${project.build.directory}/generated/framework/cxf/abc-api-inline.wsdl</wsdl>

            <!-- **bindingFile added by me** -->
            <bindingFile>src/main/resources/customBindingFile.xjb</bindingFile>

          </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>

  <!-- **dependency added by me** -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</plugin>
```

The issue that I have is my schema file **abc-api.xsd** resides in some other project, so when I try to do maven install to generate my classes, I get error saying **abc-api.xsd is not a part of this compilation**.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.3:wsdl2java (generate-sources)
>   on project : Execution generate-sources of goal
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.3:wsdl2java failed:
>   file:/I:/project/src/main/resources/customBindingFile.xjb [9,56]:
>   "file:/I:/project/src/main/resources/abc-api.xsd" is not a part of
>   this compilation. Is this a mistake for
>   "file:/I:/project/src/main/resources/jaxb_binding.xml"? -> [Help 1]

And if I remove the schemaLocation attribute from *customBindingFile.xjb* it does not work and gives error:

> XPath evaluation of "//xs:complexType[@name='MyClass']" results in
>   empty target node

So my question is how can I avoid providing the specific schema file name/location in *customBindingFile.xjb* and just have it applied to whatever xsd it's using to generate the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from our Architect, I was able to resolve this issue. I added a jaxws binding file and used prefix-less xpath query in there to match my request elements.
This way I don't need to provide schema location anywhere and it will be applied to the specific WSDL based on the XPath query.

**jaxws_binding_inheritance.xml**

```
<jaxws:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="inheritance xjc"
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1">

  <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>

  <jaxws:bindings
    node="*[local-name()='definitions']/*[local-name()='types']/*[local-name()='schema' and 
          (@targetNamespace='urn:net:mycompany:api:abc')]">

    <jaxb:bindings
      node="//*[local-name()='element' and 
            not(@name = 'ExcludeThisRequest' or @name = 'AlsoExcludeThisRequest') and 
            (substring(@name, string-length(@name) - string-length('Request') +1) = 'Request')]/*[local-name()='complexType']">
      <inheritance:implements>com.kuldeep.CommonRequest</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>

  </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

And added that jaxws binding file (jaxws_binding_inheritance.xml) under `wsdloption` for the wsdl where I wanted to apply that.

**pom.xml**

```
<wsdlOption>
  <wsdl>${project.build.directory}/generated/framework/cxf/abc-api-inline.wsdl</wsdl>
  <bindingFiles>
    <bindingFile>src/main/resources/jaxws_binding_inheritance.xml</bindingFile>
  </bindingFiles>
</wsdlOption>
```